# Linear Transformation Basis for Range and Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q: 2\times2$ Matrix${}\to{}$ Function
$$\begin{pmatrix}a& b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto at^2+bt+ct+d $$

Find bases for it's range and kernel. Find dimensions of the range and kernel.

Having problems starting this problem, I think I need to set the polynomial equal to zero not sure. ny help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand your syntax. Q is a function that maps a 2x2 matrix to a function?

Comment: Do you know how to find the range and kernel of other linear transformations?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with the kernel.

If $at^2+bt+ct+d=0$ then $$\begin{align}a&=0\\b+c&=0\\d&=0\end{align}$$

The system is in echelon form with pibots $a,b,d$. The variable $c$ is free. We give it sone non-zero value and solve for the others. $(a,b,c,d)=(0,-1,1,0)$. This corresponds to the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ That is a basis of the kernel.

For the range we can extend the previous basis to a basis of the whole domain and take their images by the map.

See that $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ together with the previous one for a basis of the entire space. Taking their images by the map we get

$p_1(t)=t^2, p_2(t)=t,p_3(t)=1$

This is a basis of the range.